# Creating a dynamic formula so it takes a number within a cell as the row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

I have a master sheet, that holds all data in a matrix form (Criteria along the top i.e. Level 0,1,2,3,4,5) and criteria along the side (e.g. Organisation, Governance, Finance, Strategy). Within the master sheet, there is data that matches these criteria, and therefore plotted in the matrix. However, there is not data for all criteria, and therefore, there are blanks.

I would like to use this master sheet as the data source, and use the same format, but i would like to divide each section (I.e. Organisation, Governance, Finance, Strategy) into its own sheet and display the data for that criteria only.

I will also want to make this dynamic to ensure that if the criteria was changed in the future, the sheets would still work.

Therefore, I am using the following formula

```
=(UNIQUE(FILTER('MasterSheetGrid'!D8:I8,'MasterSheetGrid'!D8:I8<>"")))
```

This formula works well, however the row numbers are not dynamic and the formula may break in future. Therefore, i am wanting to use the following formula

```
=MATCH($C6,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0)
```

to search for the row number, and then use this formula or output as the numerical row number in the formula above, but i receive an error each time.

```
>=(UNIQUE(FILTER('MasterSheetGrid'!D" &(MATCH($C8,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0)& ":I" &(MATCH($C8,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0)& ",'MasterSheetGrid'!D" &(MATCH($C8,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0)& ":I" &(MATCH($C8,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0)& "<>"")))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `UNIQUE` doesn't work on rows, by the way. You can use `INDEX('MasterSheetGrid'!D:I,MATCH($C6,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0),0)` to get your data range. Use that with LET so you don't have to repeat it in the FILTER formula.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had managed to get Unique to work on rows before, so thats strange! Will the suggested formula provide me with multiple values? or just the first match?

Comment: Match will give you the row number and it then filters columns D:I on that row. I forgot you can specify TRUE as the second argument to UNIQUE to have it work on a row!

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful, if you leave an answer i will happily upvote and mark as solved. I have amended the formula to use your suggested and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
INDEX('MasterSheetGrid'!D:I,MATCH($C6,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0),0)
```

to get the desired row. So then something like:

```
=LET(DataRange,INDEX('MasterSheetGrid'!D:I,MATCH($C6,'MasterSheetGrid'!$C:$C,0),0),UNIQUE(FILTER(DataRange,dataRange<>""),TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rory, was really helpful. I have another question. I have replicated the logic and formula above to find the row of a value, and i am after the same outcome.

Comment: @654lf456 I don't follow - if you have the same formula and want the same outcome, what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry, i did not mean to post that comment. It was half completed but i realised what i was doing wrong